# Can I consider electron scattering with grain boundaries in metal as a tunneling process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, scattering, quantum-tunneling

I am reading about the Mayadas-Shatzkes model (MS model).

1. when electrons are scattered with the grain boundary, there is a probability that it will be transmitted to the other side of the grain boundary(R-->0) or reflected(R-->1).
2. In the original paper by Mayadas-Shatzkes, the Grain Boundaries are drawn as an energy wall/barrier perpendicular to the electron trajectories or direction of current or electric field E.

my questions:

From point 1 and 2, I got an impression that this scattering seem like an electron tunneling as particle in a box model. Is this analogy correct?

In other words, can I consider electron scattering with grain boundaries as a tunneling process? or it is completely irrelevant since they use two different physics framework, semi-classic for MS model and QM for particle in a box?

Comment: At some level, what is the difference between treating the physics as tunneling vs treating it as an impedance mismatch?

Comment: if you are referring to this "Impedance is the opposition by a system to the flow of energy from a source." (from wiki), well, yeah...phenomenologically, I see there is no differences. On the other hand, I feel like "But for sure tunneling is tunneling, there is no classical phenomena that can equal it. "
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching